# Security risks for Users using separate logins versus one generic login for the same database

Tags: security, ipv4, share-credentials

We have several test databases that our support staff need to use.  These systems have actual production data.  For security reasons what is the proper and concise argument for each user having their own login versus a generic login for the entire team?  How does identifying the public IP play into knowing who is logging in when?

Comment: Obviously you shouldn’t have production data, that’s how production data is leaked accidentally, and that’s much more of security concern than a common user into a test database. Why are you allowing users outside of your network (public ip address) connect to a test database? Being able to identify whom is accessing your system is important if your going to make it possible to connect from outside of your intranet network

Comment: The users outside the network are remote support staff employees.  I do not agree that we should be logging in with one generic username and password so I need some help with the security argument and detailed IT information to present the argument.

Comment: If they don’t accept the role based and user identification arguments for individual access to the database, then your trying to fight, what’s likely a losing battle.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: how are the users consuming the data? through an application?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Our end users are companies that access and input data via a web application.

Answer (score 1):

From a security POV there are fewer risks with per-user logins and it is a good idea as you can get much finer control as to who can read and write to what tables - as well as better logging.

There are (manageable) disadvantages to this approach, but they are not around reduced security.  These include -

- Greater likelihood of breaking the application by having incorrect permissions.
- Greater management complexity
- Risk of incomplete backups.

Allowing database connections from a Public IP is a bad idea.  Logging public IPs gives a crude indication of the user accessing the data.  This can be much more securely implemented by requiring remote users connect to your network across a VPN so they become part of your LAN.  This has multiple advantages including greater protection of who can see the database, better control of access, and ensuring data is not communicated unencrypted across the wider internet - which prevents third party snooping and man-in-the-middle attacks.

It sounds like the company is prioritizing ease of development over security. That probably won't end well.

Comment: This is great!  Thank you for answering.

Comment: Just to add to this good answer, I have 1000+ probing attempts per day so the risk of a hacker finding your DB and breaking in isn't and matter of IF but WHEN it happens.  Once they detect the open port they will start attempting to guess passwords by brute force.

Comment: @einsem1 To alert cybernard of your question you need to mension his name in your post prefixed by an "@" (you can only have one of these notices in a comment) Id suggest deleting your previous comment and reposting it to notify him.

Comment: I really appreciate the additional information. Thank you, @cybernard. Can I ask how big is your company so I can put some reference to the number of probing attempts?

Comment: @einsem1  This is my personal website, a company of 1 if you will.

Comment: @ramhound This is great! Thank you for answering!

Comment: @einsem1 - I didn't submit an answer.

Comment: @davidgo Thank you for the detailed response.  It is very helpful!